# Retry failed upload on AWS S3 using Spring Cloud AWS

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, spring-cloud

I am working on a solution to upload files to AWS S3 using spring cloud. I have defined following variables in application.properties file.

> cloud.aws.credentials.accessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> cloud.aws.credentials.secretKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> cloud.aws.region.static=us-east-1
>
> cloud.aws.stack.auto = false
>
> cloud.s3.bucket=wXXXXXX1

Now i need to add one feature to set custom retry count, in case the load fails due to any reason. I believe this should be configurable using spring cloud variable, but I am unable to figure out what will be the name of this variable.

Can you please help me with the name of this variable(for setting s3 retry count), or the documentation to all the supported properties of AWS Spring Cloud.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure if AWS Java SDK provides something for that. When you try to upload an object to a AWS bucket, two types of exception can be thrown:
 1. AmazonServiceException
 2. SdkClientException

As alternative you can implement the retry mechanism yourself. It will be something like:

```
@Value("${retryCount}")
private int retryCount;

private int alreadyTried = 0;

public void upload(object){
  alreadyTried ++;
  try{
     uploadToAwsBucket(object);
  } catch(AmazonServiceException | SdkClientException e){
     if(alreadyTried < retryCount){
       upload(object);
     }else{
       alreadyTried=0;
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
   }
 }
```

An at the end you define the property **retryCount** in your configuration file.

Comment: Hi Ramin, thanks for your answer, but this is a very naive approach. I am looking for the name of the property in which we can assign a custom value for retry count as I am using spring cloud,

Comment: i found other documentation which is posted you as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I see. Then you should check the official documentation for ClientConfiguration, it has many functions to tune its behaviour regarding retry logic:

- *withRetryPolicy* it allows you to choose a retry policy
- *withMaxErrorRetry* Sets the maximum number of retry attempts for
  failed retryable requests (ex: 5xx error responses from services)
- *withRequestTimeout* Sets the amount of time to wait (in milliseconds)
  for the request to complete before giving up and timing out [...]
- *withThrottledRetries* Retry throttling is a feature which
  intelligently throttles retry attempts when a large percentage of
  requests are failing and retries are unsuccessful [...]

RetryCondition The hook for providing custom condition on whether a failed request should be retried
maxErrorRetry
honorMaxErrorRetryInClientConfig (whether to respect the configuration setting mentioned above)

you can find more information from amazon official documentation:

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/section-client-configuration.html

Comment: Thanks Ramin, But I need to achieve this using spring cloud.